# Where did viruses come from, according to Young Earth Creationists?

Tags: young-earth-creation, biology

[Viruses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virus) are quite nasty germs. Whereas bacteria serve many useful purposes and we need them, I wonder what the purpose of viruses in God's creation could be. Does Young Earth Creationism address what role viruses have in the world?

I'd like to hear the YEC view on the following points:

1. Where did viruses come from?
2. What is their purpose?
3. Were viruses created? If so, by whom?
4. Does the Bible say anything applicable?

If the Old Earth Creationist view is significantly different, please notify me. I expect them to be similar, but might ask another question focused on OEC if relevant.

Answer (score 13):

The notion that all viruses are bad is worth challenging. In 2008 paediatrician [Dr Lawrence D. Rosen, MD](http://www.thewholechild.us/integrative_/dr-lawrence-d-rosen-moder.html) published a blog post entitled [Viruses and Health: Not all bad?](http://www.thewholechild.us/integrative_/2008/03/viruses-and-hea.html) which looked at two interesting cases and concluded:

> In both of these cases, it appears that viral infections may indeed
>   confer some sort of protection or health benefit to the host.  Is this
>   true in all circumstances?  Of course not.  But the converse - that
>   these viruses are always a health threat in all people, is equally
>   unlikely.  It behooves us to be very, very careful when considering
>   eradicating viruses from our bodies, particularly when the cure is
>   potentially worse than the infection.

In addition, cancer research scientists are now looking at using (modified) viruses in order to combat this disease.<sup>[ScienceDirect](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1359644605034835) | [Montana State University](http://eu.montana.edu/pdf/outreach/msuscizone3.pdf)</sup>

Viruses are not mentioned in the Bible and whether they are technically living things is subject to continued discussion. In terms of their origin, the [regressive and cellular hypotheses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virus#Origins) therefore don't entirely conflict with the Christian view; however the predominant view among creationists is that viruses are part of the original creation. Along with the rest of Creation, viruses were subject to The Fall, corrupting their original intended nature. The examples above show that viruses may be (or may have been) beneficial to health. In addition there is a theory called the Horizontal Gene Transfer (or horizontal gene flow) which may explain to some degree a purpose for viruses:

> that genes picked up from somewhere in the environment rather than
>   inherited from parents may help to explain rapid adaptation and the
>   interesting pattern of DNA in animals.<sup>[Answers in Genesis: Why Did God Make Viruses?](http://www.answersingenesis.org/articles/aid/v4/n1/why-did-god-make-viruses)</sup>

Comment: The "health benefits" in that blog post are both being less subject to some other disease.  I thought that pre-Fall, there was no disease.  So this doesn't give much insight into original intended nature, does it?

Comment: @RexKerr Yes and no. In the same way that we couldn't survive without the bacteria that live in our gut, but these same bacteria can be harmful in other contexts - a viral infection (the presence of a virus) does not necessarily have to equate to a disease (ie adverse effects)

Comment: @Waggers - I agree in principle, but the examples weren't of something that would be useful in an unfallen context.  Infection by herpes makes you less likely to die of plague?  Interesting...but it leaves the "original intended nature" conjecture unsupported (unless the original intended nature was that they would play a role after the fall).

Comment: @RexKerr I think that's where the "horizontal gene transfer" theory comes in - that viruses would have been used to increase the diversity of Creation (kind of like the theory of evolution on fast forward, as I understand it)

Comment: Okay, but horizontal gene transfer among multicellular organisms is so rare that it wasn't even _detected_ until a few years ago.  One can postulate, without evidence, huge numbers of changes that could eventually make things sound plausible (e.g. viruses that can repeatedly infect germline tissues across a wide range of species and cause no sterility and (on and on and on)).  If this is the best answer out there--and for all I know it could be--it's worth noting that it's very speculative (to be charitable).

Comment: @RexKerr Perhaps, although we then get into opinions on the theory rather than just answering the question (ie pointing out that the theory exists). As things stand I'm content that I've answered dancek's question.

Comment: @Waggers I revised the question after getting some comments and [discussing it in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2305193#2305193). Perhaps you want to adapt the answer accordingly.

Comment: Is this the YEC view of viruses or your own? Do you have any sources demonstrating the former? What does challenging whether all viruses are bad have to do with the YEC position?

Comment: @Mark_Trapp Answers in Genesis is primarily a YEC resource. The Horizontal Gene Flow theory is from there. The viruses being good/bad thing addresses whether viruses could have been part of a perfect creation and the parts of the question asking about purpose

Comment: The "not living things" is... somewhat tricky. Certainly in the virions state they display no such signs, but when in contact with a cell  they do. Most sources will simply state that there is no current definitive answer whether they are classified as alive or not.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks, I've changed that sentence to reflect that

Comment: @Waggers Sorry to belabor the point, but is what Dr. Rosen, the Science Direct article, and Wikipedia said *what YECs actually believe*, or is that your personal synthesis? Do you have secondary sources that confirm what these sources say is an actual YEC position? If they're not the basis for YEC belief, they have no place in the answer: this question is about the origin of viruses *according to YECs*.

Comment: @Mark_Trapp The question is also about "the *purpose* of viruses in  God's creation" according to YECs, and makes the assertion that viruses serve no useful function. In order to explain the former it is important to question the latter. The point of an answer here is to help the OP, and as you can see from the first comment above the OP found that part of my answer useful.

Comment: @Waggers I'm not sure how that addresses my concern. Do you have secondary sources that confirm what you've answered here—the ideas from Dr. Rosen, ScienceDirect, and Wikipedia—is an actual YEC position? It might be a "very interesting" answer, but there's nothing here that shows it's actually the right one.

Comment: @MarkTrapp On StackExchange the "right" answer is the one the original poster finds the most helpful/useful. I've already explained how those ideas support the creationist position that viruses could have been part of a perfect creation. If your concern is that I've used some non-YEC-specific resources to explain my answer (alongside resources that ARE YEC-specific) then I'm afraid I don't think that's a valid concern.

Comment: @MarkTrapp To prevent prolonged discussion here and to gather input from the wider community, I've asked this question on  meta: http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/737/which-resources-should-be-used-to-answer-doctrine-questions